# does anyone have parasoft .test or jtest experience

Tags: parasoft

First i have no experience on parasoft .test or jtest experience. I have read the datasheet that the product could automatically generate unit test.

but I am woundering how useful the auto generated unit test are. Does it really do not need any other effort by developer?

any experience sharing are welcome.

thanks a lot!

Answer (score 7):

We used JTest for our product recently. We didn't use the standard product, we used the Eclipse Plugin. The standard product is built on the OSGI framework (read: it's like Eclipse), but you have to import and create your projects. We were already using Eclipse, so it made sense for us to simply use the plugin, which has all of the same capabilities.

While there are many things that JTest can do for you, there are also many irritating things about it. For example, Jtest's static analysis tool is what is really worthwhile, IMHO.  It can look for lots of errors and has a pretty good reporting system. But, while unit test generation is okay, but I think I spent as much or more time fixing and enhancing the generated tests than I would have just making them myself. Administering Jtest is also somewhat complicated and involved.

The built-in mechanisms to make unit tests, stub objects, parameterized unit tests, etc. are not well documented. At least, my little brain couldn't make good use of them in the two years we used the product. However, a lot of their super awesome features (like GUI tracing, command-line interface, the Bug Detective, reporting system etc.) all require extra, very expensive licenses.

Really, Jtest just gives you an easy way to manage the execution of static and unit testing. But it's *really* expensive. I can't believe they charge thousands of dollars per license of that stuff. You'll also find that they will want to train you, which you almost need because the documentation is pretty bad. Which is odd, because the user's guide is like 900 pages long.

But here's a big hint: you can do it for free. If I had to do it over, I would have pushed hard for using these products (which, oddly enough, look and feel *very* similar to Jtest)
http://code.google.com/javadevtools/codepro/doc/index.html

I wouldn't get Jtest thinking that this will be a small something to add to your developer's routine. Jtest can become a huge time and process sink.

Answer (score 2):

Jtest is very very useful.Yes it generates it own test cases which requires lot more efforts for fixing them.I use it in different form.I delete all the generated unnecessary test cases.I made one another file which create database connection and set various other parameters sets.Also after configuration the code will work without mocking if all of the code is ready and if it is not ready than you can stubs the required methods.

Static code analyzer is good(for checking null pointer exception)
Checking code conventions is very good.
Write your custom code guidlines as use cases and execute it on your code.

Code coverage.

Debug while testing.

Answer (score 0):

The auto generated unit tests still needs a developer to decide what results are correct or not, so you have to sit down and do the job. A lot of the boiler plate code is of course auto generated, so a small time saver there. I haven't used it much, but did evaluate jtest for an earlier employer. Seemed like a great product, if I remember correctly. :)

Answer (score 0):

Alas there will never be a silver bullet that addresses all unit testing requirements, but JTest & .Test (& C++Test for that matter)  about as close as you will get. Uggwar is correct that the developer will still need to verify outcomes for the basic auto generated tests, however there is a whole lot more to it.

These tools can be used to create basic regression tests, these are there to tell you when something has changes, not whether what it is testing is right or wrong. You can also trace a running application and then generate JUnit/NUnit/CPPUnit tests that recreate what was going on in the application. These tend to be far more useful tests, which are used as regression tests for items of functionality.

Other functionality includes the ability to generate stubs, use spreadsheets as datasources and provide an object repository. There is a while lot more too ....

Give them a try.

http://www.parasoft.com